# Padding data over TCP

Tags: c, networking, tcp, padding

I am working on a client-server project and need to implement a logic where I need to check whether I have received the last data over a TCP socket connection, before I proceed.
To make sure that I have received all the data , I am planning to pad a flag to the last packet sent.I had two options in mind as below and also related prob.

i. Use a struct as below and populate the vst_pad for the last packet sent and check the same on the recv side for its presence. The advantage over option two is that, I dont have to remove the flag from actual data before writing it to a file.Just check the first member of the struct

```
typedef struct
   {
    /* String holding padding for last packet when socket is changed */
    char vst_pad[10];
    /* Pointer to data being transmitted */
    char *vst_data;
    //unsigned char vst_data[1];
   } st_packetData;
```

The problem is I have to serialize the struct on every send call. Also I am not sure whether I will receive the entire struct over TCP in one recv call and so have to add logic/overhead to check this every time. I have implemented this so far but figured it later that stream based TCP may not guarantee to recv entire struct in one call.

ii. Use function like strncat to add that flag at the end to the last data being sent.

The prob is I have to check on every receive call either using regex functions or function like strstr for the presence of that flag and if so have to remove it from the data.

This application is going to be used for large data transfers and hence want to add minimal overhead on every send/recv/read/write call. Would really appreciate to know if there is a better option then the above two or any other option to check the receipt of last packet. The program is multithreaded.

Edit: I do not know the total size of file I am going to send, but I am sending fixed amount of data. That is fgets read until the size specified -1 or until a new line is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the size of the data in advance, and is it a requirement that you implement a end of message flag?

Because I would simplify the design, add a 4-byte header (assuming you're not sending more than 4gb of data per message), that contains the expected size of the message.

Thus you parse out the first 4 bytes, calculate the size, then continue calling recv until you get that much data.

You'll need to handle the case where your recv call gets data from the next message, and obviously error handling.

Another issue not raised with your 10byte pad solution is what happens if the actual message contains 10 zero bytes--assuming you're padding it with zeros? You'd need to escape the 10bytes of zeros otherwise you may mistakenly truncate the message.

Using a fixed sized header and a known size value will alleviate this problem.

Comment: Alan:I do not know the total size of the file I am going to send, but I am sending fixed amount of data. That is, fgets read until the size specified -1 or until a new line is encountered. I can use strlen on the buffer to find out the actual length of data.

Comment: and of course you have to parse those 4 bytes which may arrive in 4 different recv calls..

Comment: @Alan: Thnx for the replies so far.I have partially implemented what you have suggested but I would like to know how exactly I know the size to be put in the header. I am reading a fix chuck of data from a file using fgets and transferring the same amount of size.But as its TCP I dont know exactly the size of data sent until after checking the return of send call. I am little confused on that.A pseudo code will be very helpful...

Answer (score 1):

For a message (data packet) first send a short (in network order) of the size, followed by the data. This can be achieved in one `write` system call.

On the reception end, just `read` the short and convert back into host order (this will enable one to use different processors at a later state. You can then `read` the rest of the data.

Comment: Ed: Thanks for the reply. I am already sending a fixed amount of data , but not sure whether the data fetch from the file is of the same size or less than it. The fgets and send function have the same amount of data len in their call. Are you suggesting to use function like strlen to find out actual data length to be assigned to short variable?

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, it's common to block up the data into chunks and provide a chunk header as well as a trailer. The header contains the length of the data in the chunk and so the peer knows when the trailer is expected - all it has to do is count rx bytes and then check for a valid trailer.  The chunks allow large data transfers without huge buffers at both ends.

It's no great hassle to add a 'status' byte in the header that can identify the last chunk.

An alternative is to open another data connection, stream the entire serialization and then close this data connection, (like FTP does).

Comment: Martin: Thank you for the prompt reply.I can add short as suggested by Mr. Ed below in the structure to indicate the length of the data and then loop on the recv side until that amount of data is received.I would try to implement the same first.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make use of an open source network communication library written in C#? If so checkout [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net).

Comment: The question is tagged C, and it's a low level TCP messaging application.

Comment: MarcF:Thanks for the reply. As pointed by Alan, I am coding in C.Thnks again.

Answer (score 0):

If this is truely the last data sent by your application, use `shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR);` on the sender side.

This will set the `FIN` TCP flag, which signals that the sender->receiver stream is over. The receiver will know this because his recv() will return 0 (just like an EOF condition) when everything has been received. The receiver can still send data afterward, and the sender can still listen for them, but it cannot send more using this connection.

Comment: BatchyX. By design i will be needing the same connection later on. I do not know whether the same connection will be used later on or not. It depends on users choice.